# Show a div with Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

On the click of a button, I'm trying to show a simple hidden div in a fancy box.  This is the code *that works*:

```
$("#btnForm").fancybox({ content: $("#divForm").html() });
```

But from what I've read, this doesn't seem to be the standard way to accomplish this.  I've tried each of the following, unsuccessfully:

```
$("#btnForm").fancybox({ href: "#divForm" });

$("#btnForm").click(function () {
    $.fancybox({ href: "#divForm" });
});

$("#btnForm").click(function () {
    $("#divForm").fancybox();
});
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to properly use this utility?  Here's my html:

```
    <input type="button" value="Load Form" id="btnForm" />

    <div id="divForm" style="display:none">
        <form action="tbd">
            File: <input type="file" /><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As far as I know, an input element may not have a `href` attribute, which is where Fancybox gets its information about the content. The following code uses an `a` element instead of the `input` element. Also, this is what I would call the "standard way".

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.5"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.5" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>

<a href="#divForm" id="btnForm">Load Form</a>

<div id="divForm" style="display:none">
  <form action="tbd">
    File: <input type="file" /><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $("#btnForm").fancybox();
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[See it in action on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ebotuz/3/)

Comment: Hmm - well +1 since it looks like that's a lot closer to what I need, but the fancybox is showing up blank for some reason.  No errors in the console, and the code looks right to me.  Is there a type somewhere neither of us are seeing?

Comment: i added a complete working example, at least it works for me (OSX with Safari and Firefox)

Comment: That code doesn't work with Fancybox 1.3, but using the more recent version works perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: Just a side note: the inline example in the documentation does it exactly the same way (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples)

Comment: @user2314594 sorry, but you edit had no point, it just rendered the fancybox useless because the form was always visible. Fancybox will take care of showing the hidden div.

Comment: For those who want to set the width of the opened fancybox div: You just have to give a CSS width for the `#divForm`. The fancybox parameter `width` works only on iframes.

Comment: I am working with Jade and this example works for me. Thanks.

Comment: I realize this is a bit late to answer, I just like to point out that if you would like to use fancybox on a non-a element, like input you can now use data-fancybox-href="#" instead

Comment: @Daemedeor this looks great, you should add it as a separate answer.

Comment: If it does not work, put the Javascript into ready function: `<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() {   $("#btnForm").fancybox(); });</script>` I had problems using it only in the way shown above.

Comment: @Marco thanks for your suggestion. If you put the `<script>` tag after the elements that are being accessed in the script it should work just fine. Using the `ready` function is usually the safer way though so I edited my answer.

Answer (score 12):

padde's solution is right, but risen up another problem i.e.

As said by Adam (the questioner) that it is **showing empty popup**. Here is the **complete and working solution**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.5"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.5" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>

<a href="#divForm" id="btnForm">Load Form</a>

<div id="divForm" style="display:none">
    <form action="tbd">
        File: <input type="file" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#btnForm").fancybox({
        'onStart': function() { $("#divForm").css("display","block"); },            
        'onClosed': function() { $("#divForm").css("display","none"); }
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer is better. I just want to add for other newbies that on Fancybox 2 the names changed. 'afterLoad': function() { $("#divForm").css("display","block"); },            
        'afterClose': function() { $("#divForm").css("display","none"); }

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `onStart` and `onClosed`. This should be added to the selected answer.

Comment: Thanks for the additional start and close part. It solves the problem of the box being empty initially.

Answer (score 6):

You could use:

```
$('#btnForm').click(function(){
    $.fancybox({
            'content' : $("#divForm").html()
        });
};
```

Comment: That's just a longer version of what I already had.  I thought there was a more direct way to get this, using the href config property

Comment: True, you could simply use `$("#btnForm").click(function () {
    $("#divForm").fancybox();
});`

Comment: I already tried that too.  That's one of the versions I tried unsuccessfully.

Comment: $.fancybox({
            'content' : $("#divForm").html()
        });
  failed to load external css of fancybox

Comment: @aurbano in your answer in the end add ')' before last ';'

Answer (score 3):

For users coming back to this post long after the initial answer was accepted, it may pay off to note that now you can use

```
data-fancybox-href="#"
```

on any element (since data is an HTML-5 accepted attribute) to have the fancybox work on say an input form if for some reason you can't use the options to initiate for some reason (like say you have multiple elements on the page that use fancybox and they all share a similar class you call fancybox on).

Answer (score 2):

Simple: e.g. if div id 'mydiv'

```
jQuery.fancybox.open({href: "#mydiv"});
```

This also makes JS code functional which is inside div.

Comment: Your solution is so easy :)

Answer (score 1):

I use approach with appending "singleton" link for element you want to show in fancybox. This is code, what I use with some minor edits:

```
function showElementInPopUp(elementId) {
    var fancyboxAnchorElementId = "fancyboxTriggerFor_" + elementId;
    if ($("#"+fancyboxAnchorElementId).length == 0) {
        $("body").append("<a id='" + fancyboxAnchorElementId + "' href='#" + elementId+ "' style='display:none;'></a>");
        $("#"+fancyboxAnchorElementId).fancybox();
    }

    $("#" + fancyboxAnchorElementId).click();
}
```

Additional explanation:
If you show fancybox with "content" option, it will duplicate DOM, which is inside elements. Sometimes this is not OK. In my case I needed to have the same elements, because they were used in form.

Answer (score 1):

You just use this and it will be helpful for you

```
$("#btnForm").click(function (){

$.fancybox({
    'padding':  0,
    'width':    1087,
    'height':   610,
    'type':     'iframe',
    content:   $('#divForm').show();
        });

});
```